# conserve the second or final duplicate lines defined by two columns (all with integers and sorted)

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk

I have a problem of duplicate lines manipulation in a file.

There may be two duplicate lines defined by just two columns (the first two columns) in a tab-delimited files with multiple columns.The lines has been sorted by these two columns, this means the duplicate lines are adjacent each other. I just want to conserve the send/final line for such two duplicates.

## my current file (tab-delimited, with multiple columns, lines were sorted by the first columns)

```
1 100 A T
1 101 T C
1 101 T TT
2 1000 C T
2 1001 T A
```

## file I want, delete the first duplicate defined by the first two columns, conserve all the other lines and columns.

```
1 100 A T
1 101 T TT
2 1000 C T
```

I would like to have your helps on this text manipulation. I tried sed and awk. But, I can not do that by myself. Could you please give any hints on my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Best,
2 1001 T A

Comment: Did you try the `-u` option with the `sort` command? For example: `sort -k1,1n -k2,2n -u`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
{
    lines[NR] = $0
}
END {
    for(i=1;i<=length(lines);i++){
        split(lines[i], current)
        split(lines[i+1], after)
        if((current[1] == after[1]) && (current[2] == after[2])){
            print lines[i+1]
            i+=1
        }
        else{
            print lines[i]
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ awk -f s.awk input
1 100 A T
1 101 T TT
2 1000 C T
2 1001 T A
```

or as @ripat pointed out, use sort (together with `tac` to reverse the list first so that the 2nd match is chosen):

```
$ tac input | sort -k1,1n -k2,2n -u
1 100 A T
1 101 T TT
2 1000 C T
2 1001 T A
```

**Seriously, start accepting some of the answers you received! Otherwise the probability that people will take time to answer your questions will be very close to 0, Read the faq https://stackoverflow.com/faq**

Comment: Thanks a lot, Fredrik, for your help on these nice scripts and for pointing me out the answer accepting. I have done that according to your advice.